# Cannot find the interop type that matches the embedded interop type

Tags: c#, vs-extensibility

I have created a Visual Studios Extension using the `AsyncPackage` Class that looks something line this:

```
public sealed class Tools : AsyncPackage, IDisposable
{
    internal const string PrjCATIDCSharpFileBrowseObject = "{8D58E6AF-ED4E-48B0-8C7B-C74EF0735451}";
    private readonly List<IDisposable> _extenderProviders = new List<IDisposable>();

    protected override async Task InitializeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, IProgress<ServiceProgressData> progress)
    {
        await base.InitializeAsync(cancellationToken, progress);

        _extenderProviders.Add(new BrowseProvider(this, PrjCATIDCSharpFileBrowseObject));
    }
}
```

I am getting 4 Errors with the code CS1748 on `BrowseProvider`. What I do not understand is that the Errors it gives are for Types that `BrowseProvider` does not use. One of the errors is for `IAsyncServiceProvider`, but `BrowseProvider` uses `IServiceProvider`. `AsyncPackage` does inherit `IServiceProvider`, but I changed `BrowseProvider` to use `IAsyncServiceProvider` however this did not solve the problem. Creating a new `BrowseProvider` object anywhere in Tools shows this CS1748 error.

I have looked around and found that this error is caused by a reference DLL. I set `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Framework` to have its Embed Interop Type Property set to False, but the errors still persists.

All of my code shows no errors except when I try and create a `BrowseProvider` object from with in the Tools Package. I do not understand why creating a new object anywhere in the `Tools` Class shows errors for type that are no being used.

Answer (score -2):

Please make sure that you reference the correct dll or the nuget package in your project. Usually you get this error, when there is no reference.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32044055)